# DocuSign API - Force a Drawn Signature

Tags: docusignapi

Has anyone ever implemented a DocuSign Signing Ceremony via the API that requires the user to enter a drawn signature and ONLY allows the user to draw signature?  We have an implementation that is working but we do not want the user to select from predefined signature styles.  We want the user to draw the signature every time.

We have set the Signature Adoption to "Start on Draw" and we also have configured the API call to add tabs to the document but nothing seems to change.  Please note we are in demo mode.

But most importantly, has anyone ever implemented a DocuSign Signing Ceremony via the API that forces the user to draw a signature?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-sign-each-location) explaining how to do this.

This feature is called "Sign in each location" and is a property on the singer object like this:

```
Signer signer1 = new Signer 
{
    Email = "test@sample.com",
    Name = "some name",
    ClientUserId = "1",
    RecipientId = "1",
    SignInEachLocation = "true", // Signer must draw their signature in each tab
};   

        SignHere signHere1 = new SignHere
        {
            AnchorString = "/sn1/",
            AnchorUnits = "pixels",
            AnchorXOffset = "10",
            AnchorYOffset = "20"
        };
        // Tabs are set per recipient / signer
        Tabs signer1Tabs = new Tabs
        {
            SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere> { signHere1 }
        };
        signer1.Tabs = signer1Tabs;

        // Add the recipient to the envelope object
        Recipients recipients = new Recipients
        {
            Signers = new List<Signer> { signer1 }
        };
        envelopeDefinition.Recipients = recipients;
```

Comment: Yeah I have read it and also implemented it.  It does nothing.  The signature boxes never appear and when the document opens in DocuSign the menu remains on the left hand side of the screen.

Comment: this just forces the signature, you still need to decide where to put them by adding tabs. Let me add an example in the code

Comment: All I was showing before is how to change the recipient to require that, you still have to do the work of adding each signing "box" so that they will appear and you are not sent into freeform signing.

Comment: Thank you.  Long story short, I was able to get the Sign Here tab to appear using the X, Y position settings in your original code as we do not have an Anchor String in the PDF.  Nonetheless, the "Sign Here" tab appears and defaults to Draw when the user clicks on it.  That's great but the user can still toggle the menu to select a signature style.  We DO NOT want this.  We DO NOT want the user to be able to select a predefined style.  We always (and only) want them to draw their signature.  Why won't DocuSign let you disable ALL predefined signature styles and force the user to DRAW only?

Comment: Maybe you don't have this feature enabled on your account. can you do that, not using code, but from the web app? If not - then you don't have it in your account. You can try to create a new developer account, they should have these. Or our support can add this feature for your account.

Comment: https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-draw-each-signature read here how to do this from the web UI

Comment: Howdy.  Turns out I accidentally deleted this line, SignInEachLocation = "true".  Once I added it back in (under Signer Signer1) the user can now ONLY draw.  This is great.  This is exactly what we want.  You should do a full example with a link to a demo of the working code.  A lot of people want this and seem to give up.  Thanks a million for all your help and over the weekend.  I know some people who are going to be very happy.